# Ansible create tar.gz with archive module from a list

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to find files older than one day in Ansible and after that, create a tar.gz of those files, I've tried `archive` module, although it is creating only a tar of the last element in the list. Is there any way to create tar.gz including all files?

Below is my script:

```
  - name: Check all files
    find: paths=/myfiles
          file_type=file
          age=1
          age_stamp=mtime
    register: files
    failed_when: files.matched < 10

  - name: Remove previous tarFile
    file: path=/tmp/test.tar.gz
          state=absent

  - name: compress all the files in tar.gz
    archive: path="{{ item.path }}"
             dest=/tmp/test.tar.gz
             format=gz
    with_items:
        "{{ files.files }}"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> it is creating only a tar of the last element in the list

It is creating and overwriting `/tmp/test.tar.gz` for each file in the loop. When you check, you see only the last one.

---

If you look at the [`archive` module docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/archive_module.html), you will see:

> `path` Remote absolute path, glob, or **list of paths** or globs for the file or files to compress or archive.

So you can provide the list of files as a value for the `path` parameter:

```
- name: compress all the files in tar.gz
  archive:
    path: "{{ files_to_archive }}"
    dest: /tmp/test.tar.gz
    format: gz
  vars:
    files_to_archive: "{{ files.files | map(attribute='path') | list }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

i have created multiple zip files using below method.

```
- name: 'Create zip archive of {{ date_input }} NMON HTML files'
  archive:
    path: /tmp/{{ inventory_hostname }}_*.html
    dest: /tmp/NMON-{{ inventory_hostname }}.zip
    format: zip
  when: option == "5"
  delegate_to: localhost
```